# Is it possible to solve $x\sin(x) = 7$ algebraically?

Tags: trigonometry

> $$x\sin(x)=7$$

The only method to solve this that comes to my mind is to draw the left side of this equation. However, there is an infinite number of solution. Is it possible to come up with something like $x=x_o+nT$ where T is the "period"?

Comment: What makes you think that the solutions should be periodic?

Comment: I don't there is a nice solution unless maybe you allow the Lambert-W function.

Comment: In the limit as $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$, the solutions probably approach being periodic with a period of $T = \pi$, but that certainly won't be the case near 0.

Comment: The answer could better be found using graphical and numerical methods than algebraic methods...the $x \sin x$ function gums everything up.

Comment: Sooner or later, you will learn that functions can be approximated much better than with Taylor series (Padé approximants for example). Using those, we can get much better estimates of the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, only numerical methods will allow to find the almost exact solutions.

However, the solutions can be approximated if, as you surely noticed from the plot of function $$f(x)=x\sin(x)-7$$ the roots are very close to $n\pi$ as soon as $n\gt 2$ (we just focus on the positive roots since if $x$ is a root, $-x$ is a root too).

Expanding $f(x)$ as a Taylor series around $x=n\pi$, we get $$f(x)=(\pi  n \sin (\pi  n)-7)+(x-\pi  n) (\sin (\pi  n)+\pi  n \cos (\pi  n))+(x-\pi 
   n)^2 \left(\cos (\pi  n)-\frac{1}{2} \pi  n \sin (\pi  n)\right)+O\left((x-\pi 
   n)^3\right)$$ Using $\sin(n\pi)=0$, $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$ and ignoring the higher order terms, we then can solve the quadratic for the different cases where $n$ is odd or even. Doing it, for even values of $n$ the equation is $$F_{2n}=x^2-2 n \pi   x-7=0 \implies x_{2n}=n\pi  +\sqrt{\pi ^2 n^2+7}$$ 
$$F_{2n+1}=x^2-(2n+1) \pi   x+7=0 \implies x_{2n+1}=\frac 12 \left((2n+1)\pi +\sqrt{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2-28}\right) $$

For illustration purposes $$x_{10}=5 \pi +\sqrt{7+25 \pi ^2}\approx 31.6372$$ $$x_{11}=\frac{1}{2} \left(11 \pi +\sqrt{121 \pi ^2-28}\right)\approx 34.3538$$ while the "exact" solutions would be $31.6390$ and $34.3523$.

You could have other approximations making one single iteration of Newton method: this would give as estimates $$x_{2n}=2 n\pi  +\frac{7}{2n \pi  }\qquad x_{2n+1}=(2 n+1)\pi  -\frac{7}{(2n+1) \pi  } $$ which would give $x_{10}\approx 31.6387$ and $x_{11}\approx 34.3550$.